# Visual cues for enhancing user behavior

Tags: user-expectation, indicator, visual-cues

I have been working on a digital project where the product is an online presentation software where the user(Teacher) has presentation slides to select and conducts presentations to the students.

- The user buys slides from the marketplace which get added to the library of the software.
- The slides can only be moved and cannot be copied. So, the user creates a folder and moves slides into it to organize them. They can also self upload pdf files etc. in that folder.

My question is, when the user deletes the folder(on the main page), how can we let the user know that only the self-uploaded content was deleted and the bought content was moved back to the main page of the library? an animation? Text Toast?

Maybe it is self-evident on the main page, since moved content will visibly take space and show itself. But what if the user is deleting a folder inside a folder?

Please refer to the images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, this is not a common paradigm for purchased items which will likely require teaching the user along the way.  Conflating "purchased" slides and "user created" slides is not bad in itself, but it may worry users unnecessarily.

If you keep the design described, at a minimum you would want a popup message explaining where the purchased items went.  An animation would be confusing to some users, and possibly even unsettling if they don't understand why the slides are moving.  Users that love organization may dislike having slides dumped into a parent folder.

As an alternative, a more common paradigm is a "purchased slides" section that users could see (or expand) regardless of which folder they are in. Think Microsoft Visio where there's a toolbox section on the left that a user can pull from at any time. This would eliminate having to pretend that these slides are moving to the parent folder, and at the same time eliminate any question about whether someone will "lose" something they've purchased.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the feedback. Everything goes into the library if purchased only, So the buying process does not take place here. Only the organising process.

Comment: Hi @Sharan997, this would not affect the buying process.  Answer has been updated to clarify.